# Можно ли вставить в подготовленное выражение имя столбца как параметр?

Tags: php, mysqli

При использовании подготовленного выражения в Mysqli:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE ? = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $condition, $value);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->get_result()->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

возвращается пустой массив. Ошибок никаких не выдается. При этом если вставлять условие в запрос напрямую:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE " . $condition . " = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $value);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->get_result()->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

все работает как надо. Это механизм подготовленных выражений не поддерживает такую возможность(точно знаю что, если передавать имя таблицы как параметр, это вызовет ошибку, но тут ее нету) или я что-то делаю неправильно?

Прошу не кидаться тапками - гуглил, но ответа не нашел. Буду признателен за помощь.

Comment: "Можно ли вставить в подготовленное выражение имя столбца как параметр?" --- нет, нельзя

Comment: Просто в этом нет никакого смысла

Comment: А ошибки и не будет возникать. вы привязываете 2 значения в итоге запрос выглядит как `where 'xxx' = 5` в тех редких случаях когда имя колонки будет совпадать с значением выведется вся таблица, во всех остальных случаях ни одной записи, т.к. получаем ложное условие